# How to avoid duplicate values in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

[image]

```
cmbMake = new JComboBox();
cmbMake.addItem("**Please Select**");
Iterator i = products.entrySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
    Product p = (Product) me.getValue();

    if(!p.getMake().equals(cmbMake.getSelectedItem()))
    {
        cmbMake.addItem("" + p.getMake());
    }
}
```

I have a class which holds product details is there anyway to stop the same make being added to the combo box?

Comment: The same make as what?

Comment: I don't think you have to do any of this.  If you remove the selected make, the combo box will no longer work.  I think you're making an assumption you don't have to make.

Comment: Please see image linked above for example Robert

Comment: The solution to that is to provide the right item set to the combo box in the first place, not to paper over the problem by trying to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I suppose you could try this: `if (((DefaultComboBoxModel)cmbMake.getModel()).getIndexOf(p.getMake()) < 0) { cmbMake.addItem(p.getMake()); }`.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code (I added some code to yours). The code gets the values of *makes* and stores them in a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) collection, and then populates the combo box.

```
cmbMake = new JComboBox();
cmbMake.addItem("**Please Select**");

Iterator i = products.entrySet().iterator();
Set<String> uniqueMakes = new HashSet<>(); // this stores unique makes

while (i.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
    Product p = (Product) me.getValue();

    //if(! p.getMake().equals(cmbMake.getSelectedItem()))
    //{
    //  cmbMake.addItem("" + p.getMake());
    //}

    uniqueMakes.add(p.getMake());
}

System.out.println(uniqueMakes); // this prints the makes

// Add makes to the combo box
for (String make : uniqueMakes) {
    cmbMake.addItem(make);
}
```

**Suggestions**: You can use *type parameters* while using some of these, for example:

```
JComboBox<String> cmbMake = new JComboBox<>();
Iterator<Product> i = products.entrySet().iterator();
```

EDIT: Here are tutorials on [using Set collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) and [using Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).

EDIT (another way of coding the same functionality using functional-style programming):

```
cmbMake = new JComboBox<String>();
cmbMake.addItem("**Please Select**");
products.values()
        .map(product -> product.getMake())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new))
        .forEach(make -> cmbMake.addItem(make));
```

Comment: @EoinIrwin I have added another way of solving the issue using functional-style coding available with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming make is String, just create a set with all the different values and then add them to the ComboBox:

```
Set<String> productMakes = new HashSet<String>();
for (Map.Entry<KeyClass, Product> productEntry: products.entrySet()) {
    productMakes.add(productEntry.getValue().getMake());
}

// How about sorting the items before adding them to the ComboBox?
List<String> sortedProductMakes = new ArrayList<String>(productMakes);
java.util.Collections.sort(sortedProductMakes);

for (String productMake : sortedProductMakes ) {
    cmbMake.addItem(productMake);
}
```

Comment: Another option for the sorting is to use a `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Add all **values** to a `Set` and iterate over it :

```
 for(Object o : new HashSet<>(products.values())){
        Product p = (Product) o.getValue();
        if(!p.getMake().equals(cmbMake.getSelectedItem()))   {
            cmbMake.addItem("" + p.getMake());
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
cmbMake = new JComboBox();
    cmbMake.addItem("**Please Select**");
    Map products = null;
    Iterator i = products.entrySet().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            Product p = (Product) me.getValue();
            Set<String> productSet = new HashSet<String>();
            productSet.add(p.getMake());
            if (!p.getMake().equals(cmbMake.getSelectedItem())) {
                if (productSet.size() > 0) {
                    productSet.forEach(action -> {
                        cmbMake.addItem("" + action);
                    });
                }

            }
        }
```